# I've added a module to install within my Requirements file, however the module cannot be found

Tags: docker-compose, python-import, fastapi, requirements.txt

I'm interested in using the Pokemon TCG API. They had a Python SDK that I want to integrate into my application. I'm using FastAPI for my backend and running Docker. Here is the link to the SDK repository:

https://github.com/PokemonTCG/pokemon-tcg-sdk-python

Since I'm using Docker, I've already set up a docker-compose.yaml, Dockerfile.dev and a requirements.txt file. While they are all working properly and I'm able to start up my application, I can't install the SDK for some reason. When I try to import from pokemontcgsdk into my Routers file, I'm told the module cannot be found.

I've added the following to my requirements file

```
fastapi[all]==0.81.0
uvicorn[standard]==0.17.6
pytest
pymongo==4.3.3
jwtdown-fastapi>=0.2.0
pytest==7.1.2
black==23.3.0
pokemontcgsdk
```

Additionally, here is my Dockerfile.dev file:

```
FROM python:3.10-bullseye
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
ADD https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.9.0/wait /wait
RUN chmod +x /wait
WORKDIR /deps
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app
CMD /wait && uvicorn main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0
```

And here is the docker-compose.yaml file that starts it all when I run `docker compose up`:

```
volumes:
  mongo-data:
    external: true
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:6
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
  fastapi:
    build:
      context: PokemonTCG
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./PokemonTCG:/app
    environment:
      MONGO_URL: mongodb://admin:password@mongo
      WAIT_HOSTS: mongo:27017
      WAIT_BEFORE: 5
      WAIT_TIMEOUT: 60
```

However I'm still getting the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pokemontcgsdk'
This is what I've typed into my routers file, just to test if it's working:

```
from fastapi import(
    Response,
    APIRouter,
    Request
)
import requests
from pokemontcgsdk import(
    Card,
    Set,
    Type,
    Supertype,
    Subtype,
    Rarity
)
```

Am I doing anything incorrectly here?

Comment: You accidentally pasted your dockerfile again instead of your docker compose file

Comment: Sorry about that, and thanks for mentioning the error. I've edited the post to display the docker-compose file.